# Understanding Big O notation - Cracking the Coding Interview

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, big-o

I need help understanding how the author got the answer of problem 11 in the Big O chapter.

The problem goes like this:

> The following code prints all strings of length k where the characters are in sorted order. It does this by generating all strings of length k and then checking if each is sorted. What is its runtime?

```
public static int numChars = 26;

public static void printSortedStrings(int remaining) {
    printSortedStrings(remaining, "");
}

public static void printSortedStrings(int remaining, String prefix) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        if (isInOrder(prefix)) {
            System.out.println(prefix); // Printing the string
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
            char c = ithLetter(i);
            printSortedStrings(remaining - 1, prefix + c);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isInOrder(String s) {
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int prev = ithLetter(s.charAt(i - 1));
        int curr = ithLetter(s.charAt(i));
        if (prev > curr) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char ithLetter(int i) {
    return (char) (((int) 'a') + i);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSortedStrings(2);
}
```

Book answer:

> O(kc<sup>k</sup>), where k is the length of the string and c is the number of characters in the alphabet. It takes O(c<sup>k</sup>) time to generate each string. Then, we need to check that each of these is sorted, which takes O(k) time.

Notice that printing the string is not taken into account in the answer above, but I've seen the opposite in other problems.

When do you take into account printing the string in the runtime?

Would this be the correct answer **O(k<sup>2</sup>c<sup>k</sup>)**?

Also, any advice on being able to quickly tell that there's an exponential part in the runtime of this code would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: How do you arrive at O(k<sup>2</sup>c<sup>k</sup>) ? Where is the "2" coming from (textbook has just O(k c<sup>k</sup>) ).

Comment: If you want to take printing the string into account, that is O(k) for each answer found. So you can count it as part of "checking" (which is already O(k) for each candidate) and it does not add complexity.

Comment: Why string concatenation `prefix + c` doesn't affect the complexity? My understanding is that it has `O(n)` itself. What am I missing?

Comment: The complexity of string concatenation is accounted for in the final `k` factor. I thought it would be worse because it's done on every call instead of just at the end, but the total number of calls is proportional to the number of calls at the end, so it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, no. The correct answer is O(kc<sup>k</sup>) as in the book.
After you went over a string to check if its characters were ordered, which would take O(k), printing it would add only O(k) - which does not change your complexity.

Suppose testing whether a string is ordered takes `a*k` operations, and printing it takes `b*k`. Then the total number of operations for each string is at most `(a+b)*k` which is still O(k).

**Edit:** Regarding the second part of your question, going over all words with some fixed length will result in an exponential runtime complexity, since there are c<sup>k</sup> such words where `c` is the size of the alphabet and `k` is the length of the word.

Comment: I think I get it now. The string printing happens (at most) every time after the `isInOrder` has been executed and that's why it is not a O(k*k) but O(k + k). O(k + k) becomes O(2k), but we drop the constant. Am I correct? Does my logic makes sense?

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help and answering the second part of my question.

Answer (score 3):

In general the printing of a constant length string is considered constant as well, but if we want to be precise let's consider the print of a single character as the basic operation: this means that to print a k length string we have `O(k)`.

Since we have O(c<sup>k</sup>) possible strings and for each of them we have to check if it is sorted (with O(k)) and to print them (another O(k)), the total complexity became O(c<sup>k</sup>(k + k)) = O(2c<sup>k</sup>k).

But multiplying a function for a constant factor doesn't change it's complexity, and therefore the answer remains O(c<sup>k</sup>k).

Answer (score 2):

Printing the string is only an extra addition to the `k` time.

Checking whether each string is sorted is `O(k)` and say that printing it is `O(dk)` for some integer `d` (a constant). Adding the two we get `O(k + dk)`, which can be re written as `O(k(1 + d))`. Because this just a scalar we know `O(k + dk) = O(k)` so the answer does not change.