# Time Complexity of the below Solution? Its already been asked, but i still didnt understand the exponential part! Kindly explain

Tags: java, time-complexity

The following code prints all strings of length k where the characters are in sorted order. It does this by generating all strings of length k and then checking if each is sorted. What is its runtime?

```java
public static int numChars = 26;

public static void printSortedStrings(int remaining) {
    printSortedStrings(remaining, "");
}

public static void printSortedStrings(int remaining, String prefix) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        if (isInOrder(prefix)) {
            System.out.println(prefix); // Printing the string
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
            char c = ithLetter(i);
            printSortedStrings(remaining - 1, prefix + c);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isInOrder(String s) {
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int prev = ithLetter(s.charAt(i - 1));
        int curr = ithLetter(s.charAt(i));
        if (prev > curr) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char ithLetter(int i) {
    return (char) (((int) 'a') + i);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSortedStrings(2);
}
```

Comment: You're going to be wasting a lot of computation time if you generate EVERY string of length k and trash the ones that aren't in order. If you only need the in order strings, only generate those.

Comment: printSortedStrings(26); prints a 26 times for me after making the code compilable.  What's this suppose to do again?

Comment: Kindly check the below link for reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941058/understanding-big-o-notation-cracking-the-coding-interview

Comment: In reference to your earlier question. Printing the string is of linear cost k. If you have two k cost operations you equal to O(2k) since k is still linear in Big O it is written as O(k). It is not k^2 as you have suggested since it only prints it once for every string and not k times for every string.